# Pytest caplog works with custom logger when created with a fixture, but not when created directly in test method

Tags: python, logging, pytest, caplog

I have been testing my custom loggers with Pytest. Created a custom logger from Yaml config file, and wrote the following test:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def logger():
    """Fixture for providing a configured logger object"""
    logging_config = yaml.safe_load(config_yaml)
    logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
    return logging.getLogger("test_logger")


def test_logger_emits_with_queue_handler(logger, caplog):
    """Test fails if queue handler could not emit logs"""
    logger.info("This is a test")
    assert "This is a test" in caplog.text
```

This works and the test passes as expected.

However, when I try to do with without fixtures, the test fails:

```py
def test_logger_emits_with_queue_handler(caplog):
    """Test fails if queue handler could not emit logs"""
    logging_config = yaml.safe_load(config_yaml)
    logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
    logger = logging.getLogger("test_logger")
    logger.info("This is a test")
    assert "This is a test" in caplog.text
```

For reference, my configuration yaml file, custom queue handler is from my [logging library](https://pypi.org/project/logging-extras/):

```yaml
version: 1
objects:
  queue:
    class: queue.Queue
    maxsize: 1000
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  queue_handler:
    class: logging_.handlers.QueueListenerHandler
    handlers:
      - cfg://handlers.console
    queue: cfg://objects.queue
loggers:
  test_logger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers:
      - queue_handler
    propagate: yes
root:
  level: NOTSET
  handlers:
    - console
```

I am trying to understand the reason for this. Is it because a standard logger object has already been configured by the time Pytest loads and runs the test method? Is there a workaround for doing this without writing a fixture?

Comment: Just curious.  If you use a context manager and set level accordingly, does it make any difference?  i.e.  `with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):`  Not an educated guess, just know that works for me without a custom logger.

Comment: @Evan I believe I tried that, it did not work for this case. My (also not very educated) guess is that, the logger gets already initialized before pytest reach the function, and what I do in that function does not really matter anymore.

Comment: Did you finally find a way around? (facing similar issue)

Comment: No, haven't gotten any workaround.

Comment: Either `with caplog.at_level(logging.INFO)` or `caplog.set_level(logging.INFO)` is required in the first example for caplog to capture `info` level. It should not be passing. Please revisit. While you're at it, could you provide the results when using `warning` level messages in the test and printing out the loggers/handlers levels at that time?

Comment: I've been running into the same issue as @ZobayerHasan.  I wrote a very simple script that logs data and some unit tests that validate that caplog gets the logs.  As soon as I switched to initializing the logger from a file, caplog broke.  Neither caplog.set_level nor caplog.at_level make any difference and were not needed before the change to the log-based configuration.